# Filter RadioButtonList accoring to typed text in textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net, radiobuttonlist

I have textbox & radiobuttonlist.  On textbox focus Radiobuttonlist gets toggle. My problem is if I have around 1000 list of records in radiobuttonlist then it's get difficult to find specific list of word so What I need is Suppose I type letters in textbox & according to typed text I only that related list should show from radiobuttonlist.

E.g. I type cr then only list words starts with cr should be displayed.

I have done it like this.

```
<div class="filters-panel service-toggleH">
    <asp:TextBox ID="servicesFilter" placeholder="Search Services" autocomplete="off" CssClass="locator service-text" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <div class="down-icon"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="toggle-content service-toggle">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="servicesList" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="mark" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="All" Selected="True">All Treatments</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(".service-text").click(function () {
      $(".service-toggle").toggle();
});
</script>
```

populated radiobuttonlist

```
Private Sub PopulateServices()
        Using conn As New MySqlConnection()
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager _
                .ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString()
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand()
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from services where status = 'active'"
                cmd.Connection = conn
                conn.Open()
                Using sdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While sdr.Read()
                        Dim item As New ListItem()
                        item.Text = sdr("serviceName").ToString()
                        item.Value = sdr("serviceName").ToString()
                        'item.Selected = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr("IsSelected"))
                        servicesList.Items.Add(item)
                    End While
                End Using
                conn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Note:- My radiobuttonlist populating from database table

Comment: and code for binding `servicesList` is?

Comment: @un-lucky update code above

Comment: You can sort the radio button list by the text radio button have then it will be easy to find

Comment: what about rebinding the list based on rules to sort the list

Comment: @un-lucky please explain how can we achieve it..

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the radio button list by the text radio button have then it will be easy to find but if you can not then you can do something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(".service-text").keyup(function () {
           $textBox = $(this);     
           $(".toggle-content service-toggle :radio").each(function(){
                if($(this).next().text().indexOf($textBox.text() == 0))
                      $(this).closest('tr').show();
                else
                      $(this).closest('tr').hide();
           });
      });  
});
```

Comment: Its showing some syntax error in this line $(this).closest('tr').show(); Please see it

Comment: Can you provide me the generated html rendered in browser for radio button list?

Comment: It's not working because there is syntax error in that line. It's just highlighting Expected')'

Comment: Yes, there is one parenthesis missing of if statement, updated the code

Comment: script is not calling. I tried to put alert but nothing getting popup. While typing script should be called

Comment: Have you included jQuery successfully? Comment all code in change event and add just alert("hello"); Do you load .service-text dynamically through ajax?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110641/discussion-between-stupid-romeo-and-adil).

Comment: Use keyup event instead of change

Comment: showing generated html of radiobuttonlist would make it easy to write a correct selector, please add generated html, this is how you can see the source of page, http://webdesign.about.com/od/chrome/a/view-source-chrome.htm